# [console]::KeyAvailable is not identified while running from startup

Tags: powershell

The script task is to respond to keyboard commands 'F3' and 'F4'

When running the script from terminal or CMD it is fully functional
However, when calling the script from start-up cmd, the script is running but not receiving the commands from keyboard

Any idea why behavior is different when running from startup ?

This is the command line:

```
powershell  -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\PowerShell\KeyBoardTest\Keyboard-Command-Response.ps1 >>  C:\PowerShell\KeyBoardTest\Keyboard-Command-Response_log.log
```

This is the PowerShell script:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$Pause_script = 0
$exit_command = 'FALSE'

Sleep -Seconds 3
$Res= $shell.minimizeAll()

While ($exit_command -eq 'FALSE')
{
    Sleep -Seconds 1
    Write-Output "Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard"
    if ([Console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        
        $KeyPressed = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 
        Write-Output "Mylog: Identified Press of key"
        switch ($KeyPressed.key)
        {
        F3 { 
            if ($Pause_script -eq 0){
                $Pause_script = 1
                Write-Output "Mylog: F3 Detected, Pausing Run"
                }
            else{
                $Pause_script = 0 
                Write-Output "Mylog: F3 Detected, Resuming Run"   
                }
            }
        F4 {
            $exit_time = Get-Date
            [DateTime]$Date = $exit_time
            $mytime = $date.ToShortDateString() + " " + $date.ToShortTimeString()
            Write-Output "Mylog: F4 Detected, Exiting the loop at: $mytime"
            $Exit_Command = 'TRUE'
            break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log when running from terminal (and not from startup) (when pressing F3 5 times and F4 one time)

```
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F3 Detected, Pausing Run
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F3 Detected, Resuming Run
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F3 Detected, Pausing Run
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F3 Detected, Resuming Run
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F3 Detected, Pausing Run
Mylog: Waiting to Keyboard
Mylog: Identified Press of key
Mylog: F4 Detected, Exiting the loop at: 7/23/2022 2:35 PM
```

Comment: Who is the script running as during startup? System? I’d confirm that first

Comment: The command line above is saved in a Keyboard_response.cmd file, I have created a shortcut to this file and located the shortcut at the startup directory.

Comment: startup directory according to running RUN->shell:startup is:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: My first guess is that your script/console window loses focus after being launched from `Startup`. Without the focus, the console won't have access to keyboard imput.